Column flex layout is affecting the subchild
In the following code,
in Boxes1, .fourth div stretches properly,
but in Boxes2, .fourth div does not.
I do not understand the relation.
And how does .first div affecting the .fourth div is quite surprising.
I am really confused.


.first {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
}
.second {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 3px;
}
.third {
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 3px;
}
.fourth {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 3px;
  height: 100%;
}
Boxes1
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
    <div class="third">

      <div class="fourth">

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
&nbsp;

Boxes2
<div class="second">
  <div class="third">

    <div class="fourth">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>





And what do you think "stretches correctly"?

I feel the Boxes1 respects my height: 100% for .fourth while the Boxes2 does not. I am looking for the answers to this difference.

Here is the fully refined code:


.first {
  display: flex;
}
.second {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 3px;
}
.third {
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 3px;
}
.fourth {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 3px;
}
Boxes1
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
    <div class="third">

      <div class="fourth">

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
&nbsp;

Boxes2
<div class="second">
  <div class="third">

    <div class="fourth">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>




I understand you removed flex-direction: column. But i am not trying to fix it, but trying to understand what is wrong with the state as it is.
